# accessing Azure Cloud Storage with the new Configuration in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-storage, asp.net-core-2.1

Is there a way to configure my Azure Cloud storage in `ConfigureServices` of the `Startup` class, the same way I configure my DatabaseContext?

```
var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("myDatabaseConnectionString");
services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>
         (options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
```

I know I could access the connection string from within a controller by adding the IConfiguration instance to the service collection as a singleton object in ConfigureServices and then inject IConfiguration in the controller.

But how do I access this in the following class or is this a bad practice and there is a better way (e.g. in the services.Add ...) ?

```
public class ClassifiedsToProcess
{
    public static void AddMessage(string message)
    {
         var storageConnectionString = Configuration.Get("AppSettings:ConnectionString");
         storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
         ...
    }
}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I solved my problem using IOptions as suggested by Martin Brandl

**Controller code**

```
private string makeJson;
private MyAzureQueue MyAzureQueue;


public AdminController(IOptions<AzureOptions> optionsAccessor)
{
   MyAzureQueue = new MyAzureQueue(optionsAccessor);
}


public IActionResult Index()
{ 
   MyAzureQueue.AddMessage("my message");
   return View();
}
```

**MyAzureQueue class**

```
public interface IMessageRepository
{
    void AddMessage(string message);
}

public class MyAzureQueue: IMessageRepository
{
    private readonly CloudQueue _queue;
    public ClassifiedsToProcess(IOptions<AzureOptions> optionsAccessor)
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = AzureStorageHelper.getStorageAccount(optionsAccessor.Value.StorageConnectionString);
        _queue = AzureStorageHelper.GetQueue(storageAccount, "mystorageaccount");
    }

    public void AddMessage(string message)
    {
        CloudQueueMessage cloudQueueMessage = new CloudQueueMessage(message);
        _queue.AddMessageAsync(cloudQueueMessage);
    }
}
```

**Azure Options class**

```
public class AzureOptions
{
    public AzureOptions()
    {
    }

    public string StorageConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

**In the Startup.cs ConfigureServices method I added the following two lines**

```
services.AddOptions();
services.Configure<AzureOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("Azure"));
```

**And this is what my appsettings.json looks like**

```
{
"Azure": {
 "StorageConnectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=mystorageaccount;AccountKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to **avoid using IConfiguration** directly and use the [Option pattern in 
ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.1) instead.

In your example, I would e. g. implement an **IMessageRepository** which uses the storage account to persist the messages.

Your ClassifiedsToProcess class would have a constructor dependency to it and your AddMessage method would used it (it shouldn't be static since you want to access the repository).

Comment: thanks for the quick answer ! Indeed IMessageRepository seems pretty nice. Unfortunately the documentation on the option pattern is a bit confusing to me, can you give me a more specific answer in my example ? I also tried to implement an IMessageRepository based on your guidance but still can't access the Configuration part. Any idea? You can find what I did here https://pastebin.com/iSekPnN5